# Is there any alternative then Push Notifications on iOS

Tags: ios, sockets, push-notification

Push notification has some drawback eg:
1. It doesn't revert if its delivered or not
2. If device was off the push notification arrives in bunch. (I don't need the old push notifications if device was off)

Answer (score 0):

For the purposes of displaying messages to users who do not currently have your app open, there is no alternative to Push Notifications.

However, each of the drawbacks you mention does have a solution.

**Determining delivery status**

There are 2 possible reasons a notification will not be immediately delivered.

1. The device has uninstalled your app

   If the device has uninstalled your app or opted-out of notifications, Apple will return the failed recipient device token through their Feedback Service protocol. In the newest HTTP/2 version of APNS, the failed recipient token will be returned as a response to your HTTP/2 connection.
2. The device is turned off or does not have a network connection.

   Apple will attempt to deliver your most recent notification to the device when the device comes back online. If determining delivery status is essential to you, then you can supply the Content-Available flag and have your application report any successful deliveries of notifications.

**Managing notifications when devices are turned off**

By default, Apple will deliver only the one most recent notification per application when a device is turned on. This prevents the possibility of a user receiving a deluge of notifications from any single app when they turn on their device.

You can also prevent Apple from delivering old notifications by setting a TTL value. If the TTL expires before Apple is able to successfully send the notification to a device, the notification will be discarded.